# How to print index of nth-child(n) per seconds?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexing, css-selectors, setinterval

This is my code but it keeps printing -1 after prints the index of nth-child(n).

Is there any ways to print indexes of nth-child(n) per seconds? (sorry about my bad English)

```js
x=0
$(setInterval(function(){
  x++;
  i = x%3;
  n = $('.modelbox a:nth-child('+ i +')').index();
  if(i == 0){
    document.write(n)
  } else if(i == 1){
    document.write(n)
  } else if(i == 2){
    document.write(n)
  } else if(i == 3){
    document.write(n)
  }
}, 1000))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modelbox">
    <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header01.jpg" width="100%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header02.jpg" width="100%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header03.jpg" width="100%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header04.jpg" width="100%"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: document.write...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). It will call [document.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open) and doing so will remove everything in your document (hence the following `-1` you had).

Now, you have an other problem in your code in that you are using an zero-based index, while `nth-child()` is 1-based. So you need to add `1` to `i`:

```js
x = 0
$(setInterval(function() {
  x++;
  i = x % 3;
  n = $('.modelbox a:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').index();
  if (i == 0) {
    console.log(n)
  } else if (i == 1) {
    console.log(n)
  } else if (i == 2) {
    console.log(n)
  } else if (i == 3) {
    console.log(n)
  }
}, 1000))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modelbox">
  <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header01.jpg" width="100%"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header02.jpg" width="100%"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header03.jpg" width="100%"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="imgmodel/header04.jpg" width="100%"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to fix my issue.